# String manipulation with escape keys

Tags: c, string, char, escaping

I am trying to figure out a way to manipulate given strings to special characters.

For example - The string given: `"\\n"`

And i want to get:

```
// manipulations should take place here

"\n"
```

Is There any "smart" way of doing that?

Cheers.

Comment: Just a variable... ill edit it so that it will be more clear what i want (kinda hard to explain)

Answer (score 0):

```
    int i, j = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){

           if(str[i] == '\\' && str[i+1] == '\\')
                     i++;

           str[j] = str[i];
           j++;

    }
    str[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Can you explain why, please? Do you want to see "\n" or you want to see a new line(i.e. blank space).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    char str[] = "test text.\\n";
    char *s, *d;

    printf("%s\n", str);

    d = s = str;
    while(*s){
        if(*s == '\\' && s[1] == 'n'){
            *d++ = '\n';
            s += 2;
        } else {
            *d++ = *s++;
        }
    }
    *d = '\0';
    printf("<%s>", str);
    return 0;
}
```